# how to check a string is valid in ruby? A valid string will be only including either character or digital number OR both

Tags: ruby

how to check a string is valid in ruby? A valid string will be only including either character or digital number OR both. This is what I have tried:

```
str = "abc."
str[3].is_a? Numeric
str[3].is_a? String
```

"." here is also string (since ruby doesn't have char), but in my definition of valid string, "abc." is invalid.
Is there any method in ruby to check isLetter and isDigital like java does?

Comment: Can you clarify your validation test?  Why is `abc.` invalid?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.
You'll just want to use a regular expression to figure out which characters to accept/reject.

something like this would accept all lowercase and uppercase alphabet characters.

```
str = 'abc.'
str[/([a-zA-Z]+)/]
```

This works because the regular expression `([a-zA-Z]+)` matches a group `()` of one  or more `+` characters with lowercase `a-z` or uppercase `A-Z`characters.

You can use http://rubular.com/ to try different regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Regex: (Note if underscores are acceptable chars then `/\W/` is usable).

```
def valid?(str)
  (str =~ /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/).nil?
end

p valid? "123"    # => true
p valid? "123$"   # => false
```

No Regex:

```
def valid?(str)
  str.count("a-zA-Z0-9") == str.size
end

p valid? "123"    # => true
p valid? "123$"   # => false
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a regular expression?

```
>> 'abc.' =~ /[a-zA-Z]/
=> 0
>> 'abc.' =~ /[0-9]/
=> nil
```